# Java - Retrieving an Image from a site after Login

Tags: java, image, pdf, authentication, itext

Hey, folks. What I'm trying to do is write a Confluence plugin containing a servlet that generates a pdf based on the Active Directory. Anyway, there is an attachment repository on the confluence space. Problem is, when I try to create an IText image from the pdf, it gets all buggy. I'm assuming it is because the page is behind a login. Any other images work just fine.

At any rate, is there a way, in Java, I can retrieve the image in even just a `byte[]` after logging in with some sort of credentials?

Error Example:

```
Image portrait = Image.getInstance(new URL("http://*Local Network*/download/attachments/3409000/PdfTestImage.JPG"));
```

^^ throws `java.io.IOException: http://*Local Network*/download/attachments/3409000/John.Doe.JPG is not a recognized imageformat. at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:317)`

While

```
Image portrait = Image.getInstance(new URL("http://www.dominionpaper.ca/files/dominion-img/hedgehog.JPG"));
```

or anything else I put in there doesn't cause a problem. Any suggestions? I've used `HttpClient` before but I'm not positive if it'd be applicable.

Comment: how is `Local Network` defined? An actual IP? localhost? "Local Network" as is? Did you check that you're getting an image and not e.g. a 500 server error message?

Comment: Its an IP address where the local Confluence (internal dev wiki) instance is running. As far as the server error message is I don't know. The only correlation between what random internet images work and what don't seems to be the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You problem description is quite confusing. Let me repeat it to make sure I've got it right: you need to extract an image from a password-protected site, but you are not logged in into that site (user may be logged in, but not your server-side code)?

Then I'd suggest to user HttpClient to provide the correct credentials and download the file to local storage where you can process it the way you like. Note that if the site uses MS SSO, the task could be quite complicated, as your code would need a service account with AD/Kerberos.

Comment: Yes, IText seems to simply need the URL of an image to put it on a pdf, which is what I'm doing. As of now there isn't any other server side stuff other than the most basic of servlet setups (doPost and the like)